# How to prevent actions at specific date and time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to allow the users to 'create' and 'update' their submissions (bets) until a specific date and time at which point their bets are final (can no longer be created or updated).  This process would repeat each week.

I'm fairly new to Rails and I'm not sure if there is a term for this or what to search for.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this is just to add a `before_filter` (Rails 3.x) or `before_action` (Rails 4.x) to your controller. You can do so like this:

Assume you have `submissions_controller.rb` with create/update actions like so - add a before filter that will only apply to the create and update actions. You can then implement a private method in the controller to redirect the user back to your `root_path` or elsewhere and give a flash message as to why.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_if_bets_are_final, :only => [:create, :update]

  def create
    ...
  end

  def update
    ...
  end

  private
    def check_if_bets_are_final
      if Time.now >= Time.new(2014, 02, 20)
        flash[:error] = "You can no longer modify or submit new bets!"
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

end
```

Aside from your controller action though, it will probably be safer to implement a model-level validation/check to reject it if the date is past, just to be safe (or if you have other ways to update that object in the future). You can do this through the model hook `before_save`, in which you can pretty much do a similar check that I have given above.

Also, the other caveat is that comparing `Time.now` could be in a different timezone depending on where your server is. Just be cognisant of this when you do your checks, and cast the time properly with this in mind.

Comment: This makes sense but it appears to only work once as it would prevent the user from creating new submissions on subsequent weeks when the process starts over again.

Comment: I see, what you could do is save the time that you are comparing it to (in the above code that is Feb 20, 2014) in a database column in a model that you can then edit with an admin interface, OR use an environment variable if you are using heroku. That should help you solve your problem

Comment: Yes but continually moving the date forwards would allow users to go back and re-edit previous weeks submissions.  This would be problematic especially if keeping score, they could alter their score.

Comment: oh i see, so what you are saying is that there are multiple submissions that belong to a parent object, like a "contest"? In which case, why don't you make submissions belong_to a contest and a contest has_many submissions, then on the contest object there could be a `deadline_date` property that you can set and compare against

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a specific implementation, I'm not quite sure if you're having trouble specifically with Ruby or Rails. However, given your question, I would store a datetime variable in your database when the user creates the bet. Every time the user tries to 'update' the bet, check in the database whether or not it's been past that specific time away from the bet creation. Hope this helps.